# Object, key value map to JSON array

Tags: javascript

I receive data like this

```
{ '1': 'House',
  '2': 'Town Home',
  '3': 'Apartment' }
```

But I need Array of objects like this

```
[{id:"1", name:"House"},{id:"2", name:"Town Home"}]
```

Comment: Is the result Array of objects?

Comment: you have to parse the data at your end and make it just like this....

Comment: that is not a valid json you are trying to create

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object into Array of objects.

```js
const src = {
  '1': 'House',
  '2': 'Town Home',
  '3': 'Apartment'
};
const dist = Object.entries(src).map(([id, name]) => ({ id, name }));
console.log(dist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every jSon object must be like key value pairs, like your first object

```
{ '1': 'House',
  '2': 'Town Home',
  '3': 'Apartment' }
```

but your second object is not a valid json object. But you can make an Array from your first object to second one

```
[{id:"1", name:"House"},{id:"2", name:"Town Home"}]
```

if you wish to make something like this, you can follow those steps:

```
// store your object to a variable 
const a = { '1': 'House',  '2': 'Town Home',  '3': 'Apartment' }
// create array from variable 'a'
const b = Object.keys(a).map(k => ({id: k, name: a[k]}))
```

this will make variable  `b` like this

```
[{id: '1', name: 'House'}, {id: '2', name: 'Town Home'}, {id: '3', name: 'Apartment'}]
```